# Asynchronous Winsock Server's WndProc not being called

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winsock, wndproc

I'm trying to learn to make a proper Winsock server, and got the below code from some trial and effort with examples found online. My server does show up in 'netstat -an', and can be connected to via the Hercules IO debugger application. Unfortunately, none of the Message Boxes seen in the WndProc ever show up.

Sockets.h:

```
#include <winsock.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

SOCKET s;
WSADATA w;
#define MY_MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION      1048

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MessageBox(hwnd, (LPCWSTR)L"Test1", (LPCWSTR)L"Test1", MB_OK);
    switch (message)
    {
    case MY_MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION:
        {
            switch (lParam)
            {
            case FD_ACCEPT:
                break;
            case FD_CONNECT:
                MessageBox(hwnd,(LPCWSTR)L"Test2",(LPCWSTR)L"Test2",MB_OK);
                break;
            case FD_READ:
                char buffer[80];
                memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer)); 
                recv (s, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, 0); 
                MessageBox(hwnd, (LPCWSTR)buffer, (LPCWSTR)L"Captured Text…", MB_OK);
                break;
            case FD_CLOSE:
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

int ListenOnPort(int portno)
{
    int error = WSAStartup (0x0202, &w);
    if (error)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (w.wVersion != 0x0202)
    {
        WSACleanup ();
        return false;
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons (portno);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);  
    s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (bind(s, (LPSOCKADDR)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return false;
    }
    listen(s, SOMAXCONN);
    WSAAsyncSelect (s, GetConsoleWindow(), MY_MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION, (FD_ACCEPT | FD_CONNECT |
         FD_READ | FD_CLOSE));
}
```

Comment: Try passing the actual Window's handle to WSAAsyncSelect.. Passing GetConsoleWindow doesn't seem right..

Comment: I tested to be sure that it was the right handle with a message box in the main cpp, where GetConsoleWindow as the hwnd binds it correctly. If you can tell me a better function I will try, though.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's allowed to call MessageBox from inside a window procedure.  Perhaps try compiling the program as a console application (console apps can still create windows!) and use `printf` for your debugging messages instead?

Comment: The common reasons for a window procedure not getting called is forgetting to execute a message loop and forgetting to implement error checking.  There's no sign of a message loop in the snippet, there are abundant signs of a lack of error checking.  *Never* ignore the return value of a C function.

Comment: I'm already compiling as a console application -- there are no other windows.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling `WSAAsyncSelect()` to send messages to an HWND that you do not own.  Unless you have manually subclassed that window and hooked up `WndProc()` to it, `WndProc()` will never receive the socket messages.  You need to create your own HWND instead.  And make sure you also have a message loop in your code, or your HWND will never receive messages.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check the return value of WSAAsyncSelect, it should tell you what's wrong, it seems that it doesn't even register on the window.

Generally you should avoid using the console window as a HWND ( GetConsoleWindow() ) since it is a special window handled by the system and thus it may behave differnetly.
Also what calls that WndProc function? by the looks of it nothing since you use the console's window which *has its own* WndProc!

So just try to make a window for yourself and specify that in the WSAAsyncSelect call and make it invisible so it wont bother the user at all and when you're done just destroy the window!